# Why Setting POST Content-type:"Application/Json" causes a "Bad Request" on REST WebService?

Tags: vb.net, json, web-services, rest

I've a strange problem using my web service :

When I, as a client, POST a form to the REST Web Service without setting any "type-content" header, things works fine. I get the call on the server and the Json text is available.

If I, as a client, sets the content-type header of my post request to "application/json", the server reply by a "Bad Request (400)".

The web service method is :

```
 <WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="Login", Method:="POST")>
 Public Function LoginFormAccess(data As IO.Stream) As String
 (...)
 end function
```

If I don't mention "Application/Json", I can retrieve the client json-typed body, posted in the *data* stream. If I do, I get the Bad Request answer.

Why is there a such great difference of behavior concerning the content-type value and what is provide such a difference ? Does the method needs another type of parameter, or something else has to be changed or checked?

**ADDED : If the content-type is "Application/Json" AND the body is empty, then it works...!**

- Note 1 : The class responsible to answer the call **is** instantiated. (A
  trace in the new() proves it). So, the problem seems to be that the server does not find a proper method to call on that object...
- Note 2 : I've this problem using different clients, so I'm pretty
  sure is a server-side problem.
- Note 3 : I've used a WCF REST Service Application Template to create
  my project.
- Note 4 : Mentioning "ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json" and "RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json" does not help.

Comment: Try adding  `ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json` to `WebInvoke`

Comment: I tried. But without success. I added a "requestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json" since it's the request that is in Json format. But it does not work...

Comment: If I set content-type to "text/javascript" it works. What is so different with "Application/Json" ???

Answer (score 1):

When you add a `content-type` header to your *request*, you are specifying the content type of the data *in your request*, not the content you expect to see returned.

My bet from what you've posted is that you are posting XML to the service, and when you set `content-type` to JSON you are breaking the server's ability to parse the body.  Your ambiguous statement that it works "If the content-type is "Application/Json" AND the body is empty" might bear this out (assuming you mean the body of your request, not of the response).

You could prove this by adding a content type of XML instead of JSON - which, if it matches the actual body of your request, will work just fine.

In short: it's giving a "Bad Request" error because your request is specifying JSON content and you are not sending JSON.