# Using "Content-Type:application/json" to post in curl gives HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: django, api, curl, http-post, django-piston

When I make a post request using the following

```
curl -i -d "username=rock&password=rock" http://my_VM_IP/api/1.1/json/my_login/
```

it generates the required response generating a token like this(abridged):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2012 08:37:39 GMT
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Language,Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
OK{"success": {"my_token": "required_token"}}
```

But when I try the same including a header as:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "username=rock&password=rock" http://my_VM_IP/api/1.1/json/my_login/
```

it gives me the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2012 11:12:04 GMT
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Language,Cookie,Accept-Encoding
***Content-Type: text/plain***
Content-Language: en-us
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Bad Request
```

I dont understand why this happens. And also ***why does the content-Type show text/plain***, I also tried looking at some other questions like [Why Setting POST Content-type:"Application/Json" causes a "Bad Request" on REST WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724547/why-setting-post-content-typeapplication-json-causes-a-bad-request-on-rest?rq=1) . It also addresses the same problem I have. Following the answer in that I tried giving the data in various formats as

```
{"username":"rock", "password":"rock"}
```

but without success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `-H "Content-Type:application/json"` you're setting the `Content-Type` header for your *request*. The *response* will still return whatever your view tells it to return.

To return a response with Content-Type `application/json`, use something along these lines:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def json_response(return_vars):
    'JSON-encodes return_vars returns it in an HttpResponse with a JSON mimetype'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(return_vars), content_type = "application/json")

#Usage: return json_response({'admin_token': admin_api_token.token})
```

Comment: I would be glad if you could elaborate a lil. Presently I simply return the token as follows:  admin_api_token = admin_models.ApiToken.objects.create(admin=admin)
[next line]                                                               return json_success_response({'admin_token': admin_api_token.token})    P.S. The exceptions are all taken care of.

Comment: All you need to do is 1) JSON-encode your data, and 2) Add `content_type = "application/json"` to the `HttpResponse` constructor. In your case, the `HttpResponse` is returned by `json_success_response`.

Comment: Adding content_type has no effect.. and adding Content-Type as return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response),Content-Type = "application/json") gives SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: There's no reason for `content_type = "application/json"` to not work, it's straight from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__). Another example of the usage is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment).

Comment: Specific to your code, I'd try `response = json_success_response({'admin_token': admin_api_token.token});` `response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json');` `return response`

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you need to send it as a JSON format via `curl`:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username":"rock", "password":"rock"}'
```

(`"password","admin"` should be `"password":"admin"`)

---

If that's not working, try:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data '{"username": "admin", "password": "admin"}' http://my_VM_IP/api/1.1/json/my_login/
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your response. Well that was a typo, which I have corrected. If you could pls tell me Why does it still show this                           Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: @TheRecruit see the other answers, you might not have set the `content-type` in your response correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `-H` parameter of curl command, you specify content type of request. Content type of response, that you see in response, is set on the server. In WSGI application you need to specify `'content-type'` and `'content-length'` manually. Some of framework provide utility method to return JSON responses (for example, `jsonify` method in Flask).